# Any exception-free success stories of using the Android Keystore for generating keys?

Tags: android, android-keystore

Given that there many known issues with the Android Keystore and its ability to lose data or just generally fall over (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31079543/android-keystore-error-could-not-generate-key-in-keystore), [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/37051017), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30736787/cannot-generate-key-in-android-keystore), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22618171/keystore-getentry-return-null-after-change-password), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23965300/android-keystore-getentry-and-generatekeypair-throw-exceptions-sometimes) and [here](https://doridori.github.io/android-security-the-forgetful-keystore/#sthash.oypAiq7Q.dpbs)) I'm curious to know whether any developer has actually used the Android Keystore in a live app for generating keys and has not encountered a multitude of crash reports relating to the Keystore not being able to create or retrieve a key from the Keystore? How have you got around the known issues? I'm particularly interested in the scenario where the `KeyPairGenerator` class is used to generate a private-public key pair that does not require user authentication (i.e. doesn't require a screen lock to be set on the device).

**Edit:** I've included below the code that I've used for generating a private-public key pair via the Android Keystore:

```
KeyPair createPrivateKeyEntry(@NonNull Context context,
                              @NonNull String keyAlias) throws CryptoException {
    try {
        AlgorithmParameterSpec spec = getAlgorithmParameterSpec(context, keyAlias);

        KeyPairGenerator keyPairGenerator = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance(
                "RSA",
                "AndroidKeyStore"
        );

        keyPairGenerator.initialize(spec);
        return keyPairGenerator.generateKeyPair();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        String message = "Unexpected error when attempting to create a private key entry.";
        throw new CryptoException(message, e);
    }
}

private AlgorithmParameterSpec getAlgorithmParameterSpec(@NonNull Context context,
                                                         @NonNull String keyAlias) {
    int keySize = 2048;
    X500Principal subject = new X500Principal("CN=" + keyAlias);
    BigInteger serialNumber = BigInteger.valueOf(1337);

    Calendar validityStartCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    Calendar validityEndCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    validityEndCalendar.add(Calendar.YEAR, 99);

    Date validityStartDate = validityStartCalendar.getTime();
    Date validityEndDate = validityEndCalendar.getTime();

    AlgorithmParameterSpec spec;

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {
        spec = new KeyGenParameterSpec.Builder(keyAlias, KeyProperties.PURPOSE_ENCRYPT | KeyProperties.PURPOSE_DECRYPT)
                .setKeySize(keySize)
                .setEncryptionPaddings(KeyProperties.ENCRYPTION_PADDING_RSA_PKCS1)
                .setSignaturePaddings(KeyProperties.SIGNATURE_PADDING_RSA_PKCS1)
                .setCertificateSubject(subject)
                .setCertificateSerialNumber(serialNumber)
                .setKeyValidityStart(validityStartDate)
                .setKeyValidityEnd(validityEndDate)
                .setUserAuthenticationRequired(false)
                .build();
    } else {
        spec = new KeyPairGeneratorSpec.Builder(context)
                .setAlias(keyAlias)
                .setKeySize(keySize)
                .setSubject(subject)
                .setSerialNumber(serialNumber)
                .setStartDate(validityStartDate)
                .setEndDate(validityEndDate)
                .build();
    }

    return spec;
}
```